# Summarizing unique values by group over multiple columns

Tags: r, unique

I have the following problem:

My dataset consists of country-year observations for many different weapons systems (levels). I want to know how many different systems (unique values) every group (countries) had over the timespan of the dataset.

Simplified, the dataset looks like this:

```
a <- c("Greece", "Greece", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Germany", "Germany")
b <- c(1980, 1981, 1980, 1981, 1980, 1981)
c1 <- c("Weapon1", "Weapon1", "Weapon5", "Weapon5", "Weapon3", "Weapon2")
d  <- c("Weapon2", "Weapon4", "Weapon2", "Weapon2", "Weapon1", "Weapon3")
e <- c("Weapon3", "Weapon3", "Weapon3", "Weapon4", "Weapon2", NA)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c1,d,e)

        a    b      c1       d       e
1  Greece 1980 Weapon1 Weapon2 Weapon3
2  Greece 1981 Weapon1 Weapon4 Weapon3
3 Belgium 1980 Weapon5 Weapon2 Weapon3
4 Belgium 1981 Weapon5 Weapon2 Weapon4
5 Germany 1980 Weapon3 Weapon1 Weapon2
6 Germany 1981 Weapon2 Weapon3    <NA>
```

So in the example code, Germany has 3 different weapon systems deployed in total. How can I do this?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(c1, d, e)) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  distinct(value) %>%
  summarize(n=n())
```

which gives:

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   a           n
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 Belgium     4
# 2 Germany     3
# 3 Greece      4
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
 stack(rowSums(table(rep(df$a, 3), unlist(df[3:5])) > 0))[2:1]
      ind values
1 Belgium      4
2 Germany      3
3  Greece      4
```